# Relation between two integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f(x)$ be a monotonically decreasing continuous function for non-negative $x$. Let us define $g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)},\forall x\geq0$. For any two positive numbers $a$ and $b$ (such that $a\leq b$), is there any relation between the integrals $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)dx$. If not, is there any special case, where such a relation can be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Cauchy Schwarz inequality

$$\int_a^bg(x)dx\le\sqrt{b-a}\sqrt{\int_a^bf(x)dx}$$

**Edit:** This inequality  is valid assuming $f\ge0$.

Comment: ... assuming $f(x) > 0$

Comment: $f$ is positive since $g=\sqrt f$

Comment: You don't make something positive by writing it inside a $\sqrt{\ }$ symbol.  If you don't want to take square roots of negative numbers, then you could have $f$ negative and $g$ undefined.

Comment: I don't mean that I'll make $f$ positive but I understood from $g=\sqrt f$ that the OP assumed it and he didn't explicitly mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

If $F(t) = \int_a^t f(x)\ dx$ and $G(t) = \int_a^t \sqrt{f(x)}\ dx$, then
$F'(t) = G'(t)^2$.